# list column in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I have two column. one is called Goal and the other is called Projects
Under Goal, i have different choices. If I select choice then projects should display choices which are related to one of the choices and vice versa.

Eg:

```
Goal: Has choice quality, Regulatory
and Projects has more choices
```

when we select quality under goal then it should show projects in related quality and if we select regulatory then it showed show projects in related to that and vice versa.

Can someone help me how I can do that in SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

Lookup column is the answer. Check out for Look up column in internet, you will get lots of example to practice.